# I am trying to call my Scanner but its not working. What should i do?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
{
    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String s1;
    int myAge;
    int time = 6;

    System.out.print("What is your name? ");
    s1 = myScan.nextLine();

    System.out.print("How old are you? ");
    myAge = myScan.nextInt(); 

    System.out.println("Really? Cause I am " + (myAge+3) + ". " + "Lets's meet up! ");
    s1 = myScan.nextLine();

    }
}
```

//After the last command, it wont let me type anything in the terminal window. Please help.

Answer (score 3):

Add a `nextLine()` between

```
System.out.print("How old are you? ");
myAge = myScan.nextInt(); 

myScan.nextLine(); // add this

System.out.println("Really? Cause I am " + (myAge+3) + ". " + "Lets's meet up! ");
s1 = myScan.nextLine();
```

This is required because `nextInt()` only consumes the `int` value it reads and not any end of line characters following it.

The `nextLine()` will consume the `\r\n` (or whatever end of line / delimiter characters) and the next token will be available to be consumed by the other `nextLine()`.

Answer (score 0):

When you type enter after the insert of int. nextline will take enter as a line.
what you need is to add an extra nextline call after nextint as follow:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Words
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String s1;
        int myAge;
        int time = 6;

        System.out.print("What is your name? ");
        s1 = myScan.nextLine();

        System.out.print("How old are you? ");
        myAge = myScan.nextInt(); 
        s1 = myScan.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Really? Cause I am " + (myAge+3) + ". " + "Lets's meet up! ");
        s1 = myScan.nextLine();
    }
}
```